LED Light fixture suggestions
I recently moved my office to a basement room. The lights in this room were never a concern before but now I am noticing that they are blindingly white and one of them obstructs my camera quality on meetings due to it being behind my head.
The lights in the room are the standard 14in LED circular flush mounts that you can buy almost anywhere. I figured they may have a switch for changing the light temp and wattage but when I removed the housing the box does not appear to have anything to alter the current settings.
I’m considering options and wanted to see if anyone had thoughts or suggestions on what to do with these fixtures:

install a dimmer switch - I believe the lights are dimmable so I could install a switch and just adjust the light that way. But this doesn’t totally solve the problem that the lights are very white and bright when all the way on. I’ve also never installed a dimmer myself but from what I understand when following the proper safety and steps this isn’t a tough project.
swap out the LED panel/board with one that has more warmth. I haven’t been able to locate any replacement boards/panels so I think this option isn’t feasible
Totally replace the fixtures - I see a lot of the same style lights online that advertise themselves as adjustable so I could just get new ones and replace the existing fixtures. Only want to do this as a last resort if the other options are not possible.

Here’s some photos of the lights for reference (had to upload them in low quality for size purposes):




"I’m considering options and wanted to see if anyone had thoughts or suggestions on what to do" This is very opinion-based, which may lead to the question being closed. A specific question "Can I put a dimmer on these lights?" "Is it possible to change the LED boards?" are questions that can be answered here.

Most LED fixtures are designed for a fixed color temperature, e.g., 6,000 K for blue-white (confusingly termed "cold" appearing), or 3,200 K (yellowish-white confusingly termed "warm" appearing).
Unlike incandescent lamps, reducing the power might dim the light (not all fixtures are dimmable! Some may even go up in smoke with the wrong dimmer), but does not change the color temperature, unless the lamp is specifically designed to emulate a tungsten filament.
Your best choice is to get another fixture, designed for the color temperature you (and the webcam) prefer, or to get one with adjustable color temperature; such as this random example from Amazon.
Note also that some lamps do not produce the full color gamut. Such a lamp might not look too bad to the eye, but with some cameras, might the results might not be pleasing. There are premium full gamut lights, such as these at B&H Photo, but you probably don't need that expense for casual teleconference illumination.
It is possible to use colored cellophane to change the effective color temperature, though with a possible risk of creating a fire hazard. That also reduces the efficiency of the lamp.
